# Bibliography style - [AUTH YEAR]

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm looking for a bst bibliography style that I could use, but I cannot find any site where I could see any list of styles ot theirs names. I would like my bibliography to be in a format:

```
[ALSA 1992] Alsabbagh J.R., Raghavan V.V., A framework for multiple query optimization, w: 
            Proc. of Intern. Conf. on Data Eng., 1992, s. 157 − 162.  
[BATO 1986] Batory D.S., et al, Extensible cost model and query optimization in Genezis, IEEE 
            Database Eng., vol.9, No.4, 1986, s. 30 − 37.
```

I found only a similar style that is called *wmaainf*. Does anyone know where I could find a style that I described earlier?

Comment: I'm using BibTeX (using `\bibliographystyle{wmaainf}{\raggedright\sloppy\small\bibliography{bibliography}}`) to include it). My language is Polish so this is why it says `s. 30 - 37` as `s` stands for `strona`. I found wmaainf here: [link](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CD4QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tex.ac.uk%2Ftex-archive%2Fbibliography%2Fbibtex%2Fcontrib%2Fmisc%2Fwmaainf.bst&ei=CNkPUZPoIbGS0QWJ3IHgBQ&usg=AFQjCNHqnEGgiqbYj-x9v69I0VK1xt_BjA&sig2=-AbrRprz8u9-oIKgE1UIkw&bvm=bv.41867550,d.d2k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have three options:

1. find a style that comes closest to what you want [here](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html).
2. Adapt the style that comes closest to your taste. Suppose we start with `wmaainf`. Note that this style forbids any modification. In good TeX tradition that *might* mean that you are allowed to copy the style to a differently named file, and modify your copy. But I can not give legal advise here. Suppose your are allowed to do that, and your copied style is called `krajol.bst`. Open that in an editor, and replace the english strings (those are enclosed in "...") to polish strings. E.g., the function `format.pages` contains the line `{ "p.~" pages n.dashify * }`. Changing that to `{ "s.~" pages n.dashify * }` would now give the desired s. for strona. Note that more modern styles are internaionalised, meaning that they adapt to a language set with `babel`, but `wmaainf` is not one of them.
3. Make your own style from scratch with the help of `custom-bib`. You need to run

   ```
   latex makebst
   ```

   and you will be asked many many questions what your bibliography style should look like. At the end, you get your desired style file. But please read the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/merlin.pdf) before. One goody is that style files produced with `custom-bib` can be internationalised with a `polski` option, i.e., you can produce your style in Polish without having to translate anything.